# Do I need to call svnadmin pack on a regular basis

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to keep my svn 1.9 repositories as fast as possible by doing regular maintenance. I read on the [svn website](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.fsfspacking) that packing the repository is a good way to speed things up.

I'm wondering if I need to call [svnadmin pack](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.pack.html) on a regular basis (ex. once every 3 months) to keep the benefits of packing the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to do this. Unfortunately there is no way around. 
Note, that you can run this without stopping your server.

Also you should do this more often than all 3 months as the command will quickly return if no revision is to pack. I would say every week is a fine choice.

Comment: I was wondering if i was doing something wrong because, as you said, the command quickly returned. I guess we didn't reach 1000 revisions since the last pack. Thanks!

Comment: exactly! that's why you should invoke the command quite often.